# Cant stick one div under another while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have one div below another. And I want both of them to stick one below another at the top of page while scrolling.
My code looks like this-

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
$('#sticky2').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
$('#sticky2').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
#sticky {
  padding: 0.5ex;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
  #sticky2 {
  padding: 0.5ex;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
#sticky2.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
<div id="sticky2">This will stay at top of page 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But in UI the `div` overlaps each other.
I want it one below another.
And I have 2 separate `div`s specifically.

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzrjaE).
I want the second one to stick below first one.

Comment: Can you set up a CodePen with your code so we can see what's happening?

Comment: In addition to the 2 answers mentioned, you might want to try display:block; display:inline; or display:inline-block; on the sticky class.

Comment: @AlxTheRed https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzrjaE

Comment: @Chirag It looks like the issue is that the value of `top` is the same for both blocks. You need the second element's top value to offset the top of the screen by the height of the first div.

Comment: @AlxTheRed Tried that, but wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? If yes then add `top: 50px;`(`#sticky`'s height) to your `#sticky2.stick`'s css

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

function sticky_relocate2() {
  var window_top2 = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top2 = $('#sticky-anchor2').offset().top;
  if (window_top2 > div_top2) {
    $('#sticky2').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#sticky2').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
   $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate2);
  sticky_relocate2();
});
```

```css
#sticky {
  padding: 0.5ex;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

#sticky2 {
  padding: 0.5ex;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ff8;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

#sticky2.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 10001;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}


body {
  margin: 1em;
}

p {
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
Source: http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html
<p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone
  realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of
  the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
  To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
  Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this,
  it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be
  more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental
  is.The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a</p>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
<p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone
  realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of
  the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
  <div id="sticky-anchor2"></div>
  <div id="sticky2">This will stay at top of page</div>
  To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
  Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this,
  it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be
  more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental
  is.The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a</p>
<p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone
  realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of
  the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
  To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
  Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this,
  it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be
  more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental
  is.The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a</p>
<p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone
  realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of
  the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
  To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
  Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this,
  it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be
  more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental
  is.The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a</p>
<p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone
  realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of
  the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
  To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
  Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this,
  it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be
  more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental
  is.The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a</p>
<p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone
  realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of
  the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
  To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
  Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this,
  it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be
  more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental
  is.The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a</p>
<p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone
  realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of
  the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
  To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
  Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this,
  it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be
  more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental
  is.The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a</p>
  
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your id to class, because you cant repeat the same id name

```
<div class="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
<div class="sticky">This will stay at top of page 2</div>

.sticky {
  padding: 0.5ex;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

.sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

> or
>   By default div come one below one , So please try this

```
    #sticky{
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        height:auto; 
        width:auto;
    }
    #inner1{
      float:left; 
    }
    #inner2{
      float:left; 
      clear: left;
    }
    </style>

    HTML:

    <div id="sticky">
        <div id="inner1">inner1</div>
        <div id="inner2">inner2</div>
    </div>
```